# In bond markets, how does the number of banks in an underwriter syndicate grow as they share risk on larger deals?

Tags: mathematical-economics, finance, bonds, risk, insurance

If I look at a large collection of underwriter syndicates (underwriting green bond issuances), I can see there is, on the whole, a quadratic relationship between the value $v$ in USD that the syndicate underwrites (a real number), and the syndicate size $n$ (an integer strictly greater than zero),
$$
n(v) \propto v^2
$$
So, if I double the amount of money/risk they share, I quadruple the number of actors in the syndicate, and so on.

[image]

Is there any known financial idea in the theory of risk which would explain this? I might have thought this relationship would be closer to linear. This asks the question of how equally risk is shared amongst underwriters in a syndicate. Even just a reason for why we have a super-linear relationship (in this case quadratic) between financial value and syndicate size would be interesting.